# How can I add a Rect without a border?

Tags: c#, abcpdf

Is it possible to create a Rect text area with black font and no boarder or at least a white border?

Also, is it possible to add an image and not have it scale to fit the Rect?

Answer (score 3):

To make a white border

```
PDFDoc.Color.String = "255 255 255"
PDFDoc.Rect.Left = 100
...
```

Per their documentation,  "the line color is determined by the current color"

Answer (score 2):

Create rect text area with black font:

```
Dim PDFDoc As WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc

'Dimensions
PDFDoc.Rect.Left =100
PDFDoc.Rect.Bottom = 100
PDFDoc.Rect.Width = 100 
PDFDoc.Rect.Height = 100
PDFDoc.Color.String = "0, 0, 0" 'black font

PDFDoc.AddText(text)
```

But be careful. If the text is bigger than the rect then it will not appear.

There will be no border by default. If you need one, use:

```
PDFDoc.FrameRect()
```

To add an image:

```
Dim bm As Bitmap

bm = New Bitmap(filename)
'Dimensions
PDFDoc.Rect.Left = 100
PDFDoc.Rect.Bottom = 100 'N.B Measures from bottom, not top     
PDFDoc.Rect.Width = 100
PDFDoc.Rect.Height = 100

PDFDoc.FillRect()
PDFDoc.AddImageBitmap(bm, True)
```

However, I don't think it's possible to make it not fit the Rect. As I understand it,  that's kind of the point of having the Rect anyway.

Also, I recommend having a look at [websupergoo's documentation](http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm). It's pretty good.

Comment: Create an XImage object to obtain the dimensions of your image, set the Rect based on this, then call Doc.AddImage(XImage).